# No sound from audio cdrom with PyGame on RaspBerry Pi 4+, using ALSA

Tags: python-3.x, audio, raspberry-pi, pygame, alsa

I try to use PyGame to play old audio cd collection on a Raspberry Pi4 with python3.
As far as I know, have cd audio a different data structure than sound or streaming media, and audio CDs are not mounted in the file system like data CDs, therefore it needs special handling.
The following very simple programm running under Windows 10 from Python's commandline and also in PyCharm IDE:

```
PS C:\Users\manfr> python
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pygame import cdrom
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> import pygame
>>> import time
>>> pygame.init()
(6, 0)
>>> cdrom.init()
>>> cdrom.CD(0).init()
>>>
>>> i = 0
>>> while i == 0:
...     cdrom.CD(0).play(5)
...     time.sleep(10)
...     i = 1
...     cdrom.CD(0).stop()
...
>>>
```

Also in PyCharm without problems:

```
from pygame import cdrom
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
cdrom.init()
cdrom.CD(0).init()

i = 0
while i == 0:
    cdrom.CD(0).play(5)
    time.sleep(10)
    i = 1
    cdrom.CD(0).stop()
```

Result in PyCharms ‘Run’ window:

````
D:\Python-Programme\gui-beispiel\venv\Scripts\python.exe "D:/Python-Programme/gui-beispiel/CD-Project/Thread Test 10 PyGame playlist vereinfacht.py"
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

Process finished with exit code 0```
And now the same code starting in the 'Python Console' of PyCharm.
````

No problems in Windows 10 environment.
RaspberryPi complicates it a little bit more.

The same programm on my RaspBerry Pi returns no music, neither from the commandline (python 3.x) nor under Thonny Python IDE.
Running from python commandline interpreter:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> #!/usr/bin/python3
... import pygame
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> from pygame import *
>>> from pygame import cdrom
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> pygame.init()
(6, 0)
>>> cdrom.init()
>>> cdrom.CD(0).init()
>>> 
>>> i = 0
>>> while i == 0:
...     print('cdrom bussy, but I hear no music')
...     cdrom.CD(0).play(5)
...     time.sleep(20)
...     i = 1
...     cdrom.CD(0).stop()
...     print("no idea what's went wrong :-(")
... 
cdrom bussy, but I hear no music
no idea what's went wrong :-(
>>>
```

The following commands all works well:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ speaker-test -t wav -c 2
speaker-test 1.1.8
Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000 Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
WAV file (s)
Rate is 48000 Hz (requested: 48000 Hz)
Buffer size from 480 to 32768
Period size from 480 to 32768
Use maximum buffer size 32768
Periods = 4
set: period_size = 8192
set: buffer_size = 32768
  0 - Front left
  1 - Front right

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ omxplayer /home/pi/test.wav
Audio codec pcm_u8 channels 1 samplerate 11025 bitspersample 8
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
have a nice day ;)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ omxplayer /home/pi/song1.mp3
Audio codec mp3float channels 2 samplerate 44100 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
have a nice day ;)
```

That seems to me that I do not have any problems with wav/mp3 audio channels, but my raspi don't like audio tracks from the 'mounted' audio cd. 
I did also a test with the VLC player, which is installed on my raspi.
Opening the media (cdrom) and opening parallel `alsamixer` shows, that vlc communicates successfully with ALSA. E.g. I could change the loudness.
Here is ALSA’s infoscreen for further information.

```
┌────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.1.8 ──────────────────────────────┐
│   Gerät: bcm2835 ALSA                              F1:  Hilfe                │
│    Chip: Broadcom Mixer                            F2:  System-Informationen │
│ Ansicht: F3:[Wiedergabe] F4: Aufnahme  F5: Alle    F6:  Soundkarte auswählen │
│ Element: PCM [dB-Änderung: -9,58]                  Esc: Beenden              │
│                                     ┌──┐                                     │
│                                     │  │                                     │
│                                     │▒▒│                                     │
│                                     │▒▒│                                     │
│                                     ├──┤                                     │
│                                     │OO│                                     │
│                                     └──┘                                     │
│                                      59                                      │
│                                  <  PCM   >                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

So far I think it is not a problem of my raspi’s sound configuration, but a problem of PyGame. It seems that PyGame would not work propper with ALSA.
I do not know what mistake I made. Hopefully anyone else here could give me an advice.

Comment: do you have CDROM connected to Raspberry PI ?

Comment: Yes, it's an external USB CDROM with no audio output. As I described, VLC play the audio tracks and gave sound - via the analog output of the Raspberry Pi - to my external Bose SoundTouch 10. PyGame seems for me, that it sends commands to the CDROM (I can hear the tracks changing and working sounds of the CDROM), but it sends no music to the external loudspeaker. No music, no fun!!!

Comment: I don't have CDROM to connect to RPi and see this problem. I can't even check it on my notebook because I don't have CDROM a few years. Frankly I was suprised that someone still use CDROM.

Comment: The solution of my problem is very, very, very simple!!!

Answer (score 1):

PyGame only controls the audio CD (play, pause, stop, etc.). The music itself has to be taken from the audio output of the CDROM! Older devices did have such an output, but I never saw a new USB drive with such an audio output. So I cannot use PyGame for my project. Hopefully my fault will help others not to fall in the same trap.